# Maven Scala Plugin Increases Build time

Tags: scala, maven, maven-scala-plugin

I am using scala-maven-plugin version 3.3.2. When I try to execute a scala script using the plugin, it somehow tries to update one dependency 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on'. I am using a local artifactory repository to manage my dependencies.

```
23:39:37,746 [DEBUG] Determining update check for artifact org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on (/Users/akannan7/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/maven-metadata-uhc.xml) from uhc (https://repo1.uhc.com/artifactory/maven-repo)
23:39:37,747 [DEBUG] Searching for uhc.maven-metadata-uhc.xml.lastUpdated in resolution tracking file.
23:39:37,748 [DEBUG] Reading resolution-state from: /Users/akannan7/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/resolver-status.properties
23:39:37,750 [DEBUG] Determining update check for artifact org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on (/Users/akannan7/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/maven-metadata-central.xml) from central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
23:39:37,752 [DEBUG] Searching for central.maven-metadata-central.xml.lastUpdated in resolution tracking file.
23:39:37,753 [DEBUG] Reading resolution-state from: /Users/akannan7/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/resolver-status.properties
```

When I remove the plugin from project, it builds within 4 mins. If I add it back, this process runs in a loop and increases the build time of the project considerably by 12 mins. Please provide thoughts or suggestions to reduce the build time.